# One-Click Sharing on Facebook, Linkedin, Pintrest, Google+, Twitter

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, share, linkedin-api

Is it possible to share on multiple platforms via one single click.

This is what I want to do:

- I want to add a product and click on submit
- This action should share the product information along with the thumb nail and link on all the social media platforms.

This could prove to be very fruitful for users as it saves a lot of time and popups!

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any, since without popup you'll have to use their APIs separately to publish the content- and for that you'll first have to integrate the authorization of these separately.

Its not really recommended. My thinking is that people will mark your application spam if you do so. You must allow user to explicitly select where they want to share the content (like most of the apps do). And for that search for any social sharing plug-ins (i've not used any but if you'll search there are many available such plugins) that gives user the option to share individually.